# React set className by conditions dynamic

Tags: reactjs

I have a map function which should dynamic show classNames.
In this function i want to set the className dynamic. 
I tried to set the className also without the

> $

But dosen't also not work

```
this.state.antwort.map((item,key) =>
  <Col md={2} key={key} className={' ${item.gender == "Female" ? karteFemale : karteMann}' } >

...

)    }
```

But i got the error, that the classNames are undefined.
So how can i set the classes flexible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
className={item.gender === 'Female' ? karteFemale : karteMann}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nifiro's post was spot on!

You can also use the [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) package in the future if you want some complicated behavior and classnames.